# How to access SQL Relationship/Parent/Foreign-Keys in GridView's HyperLinkField?

Tags: sql, gridview, hyperlink, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a question about GridView. In my code, I have a HyperLinkField like below:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="DocumentAlbum.Name" HeaderText="Nama Album" SortExpression="Album"
                DataNavigateUrlFields="AlbumID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Extras/UploadFile.aspx?DocumentAlbumID={0}" Target="_blank" />
```

Everything works fine except for 1 thing. If you see from the picture, Document has a relation with DocumentAlbum where Document's AlbumID is taken from DocumentAlbum's ID. My goal is to show DocumentAlbum's name in the HyperLinkFieled. That is why I use `DataTextField="DocumentAlbum.Name"` `instead of DataTextField="AlbumID"`. Apparently, this does not work.

Do you guys know how can I retrieve the album's name instead of ID?

Thank you soooooooooo much in advance. This problem has been bugging me for a while.

[image: Document and Document Album]

Answer (score 0):

If you do a SQL JOIN condition between Document and DocumentAlbum, you can bring back the album name in the query that is assigned to the GridView. Then I believe you can add the album name as a column to the GridView but set the column visibility to false (it's been a while with me working with the GridView so I don't remember if you have to include the column to reference it like you're doing). Then you should be able to do DataTextField="Name".

Comment: Thanks for the insight. However, I found another solution 2 days ago. I used LINQ to manipulate the DataField but I feel it's kinda tacky and yours is more neat. I think I'll change my way to yours. Thank you so much!